# UITextView rightView border/padding

Tags: ios, objective-c

First of all sorry for the very non-specific title, but I'm not sure what the cause of the problem is.

Now for the problem itself: I'm adding a `UIButton` as the `rightView` of a `UITextView`, but instead of it being perfectly aligned with the right side of the `UITextView` there's a small "gap" (see the linked picture).

[image]

Here's the code I'm using to add the `UIButton`:

```
- (void)addCopyButtonWithTitle:(NSString *)aTitle
{
    UIButton *copyPasswordButton = [UIButton new];
    CGSize titleSize = [aTitle sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:copyPasswordButton.titleLabel.font}];
    [copyPasswordButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, titleSize.width + 16, self.defaultPasswordTextField.bounds.size.height)];
    [copyPasswordButton setTitle:aTitle forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [copyPasswordButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.5]];
    [copyPasswordButton addTarget:self action:@selector(copyDefaultPassword) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    self.defaultPasswordTextField.rightView = copyPasswordButton;
    self.defaultPasswordTextField.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
}
```

Thanks.

Alex

Comment: Not clear how it should be. What "gap" do you want to remove?

Comment: @Avt, there is a thin white line on the right of the button, that looks the `UITextView`'s background.